# How to cancel init in git

Tags: git, macos, git-init

I'm using MacOS and I initialized /User/myAccount into a git repository by mistake. I don't really want that. How can I undo the init and make it back to the original look?

Comment: Do you mean, you ran `git init` in that directory? Just remove `.git` subdirectory then.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the folder created by `git init` using `rm -rf .git/`.